# Make Boolean logic equations from circuit?

Tags: digital-logic

I think I'm doing my Boolean algebra wrong on this circuit. Could someone check my work here? 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your calculations are not correct as far as I can see, it's hard to follow where you have go the first equation.

You should follow a process as such:

1. Start by labelling all nodes. There are 6 output nodes by my count, including the output Q.
2. Write down the each equation of each node in relation to the nodes before it. You will end up with 6 equations in this case.
3. Substitute in prior equations to build up a final non-simplified equation for Q.
4. Simplify using Boolean algebra rules.

I'll give you a hint, in this particular example you will end up with a *very* simple equation that is well grounded.

Comment: "well grounded" - bit of a huge clue there!